# Can I have 2x2 workspaces in GNOME 3?

Tags: 17.10, workspaces, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and found out there is no option to have 2 by 2 workspaces. I was able to configure 4 "static" workspaces using [GNOME Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GnomeTweakTool), but I would like to have them in 2 rows by 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After you have disabled "dynamic" workspaces using (GNOME) Tweaks and enabled "static" ones (with a fixed number, 4 in this case), install a [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). It

> Arranges workspaces in a configurable grid.
>   Also:
>
> - implements keybindings for left/right workspace navigation (up/down are already implemented)
> - updates workspaces sidebar with grid configuration (use Remove Workspaces Sidebar if you don't want it).

[image]

From the extension's preferences you will be able to set your preferred layout (e.g. 2x2, 2x3, 3x3 etc.).

You may see its [GitHub page](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid) for more detailed info.

---

<sub>Officially it doesn't support GNOME v3.26 yet, but it should work fine. Otherwise, you may be able to make it work adding `"3.26"` to its `metadata.json` file.</sub>

<sub>**Update from the asker:**

It worked out of the box without changing anything. Even my old custom shortcuts worked.</sub>

### Update 2: Ubuntu 19.04

Currently the extension doesn't work with Gnome 3.32 and it might take a while before (if) it again will, because it's the current maintainer (thanks [zakkak](https://github.com/zakkak)) is looking for [for volunteers to take over maintainance](https://github.com/workspace-grid/workspace-grid/issues/120)). Suitable replacement can be [Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) which has a bit less features, but the main features are present.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me. It worked out of the box without changing anything. Even my old custom shortcuts worked.

Comment: The instructions of this plugin say `Open gnome-tweak-tool, go to “Shell Extensions”, “Install Extension” and select the .zip file` but for me on the "Extensions" Tab of the tool I did not found this option...

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent You're right, it seems that feature is removed from *Tweaks*. Please try to install directly from it's [homepage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). You can also extract the `zip` at `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: It didn't work out of the box for me on a fresh ubuntu 18.04. I had to also install gome-tweak-tools and configure 4 **static** workspaces there so I got the full grid. Workspace Grid does not (yet) support switching from dynamic to static workspaces so you need both extensions.

Comment: @swenzel That part is already assumed, see the question: "*I was able to configure 4 "static" workspaces using GNOME Tweak Tool...*" (it was wrongly written as "stacked" instead of "static" due to an edit by another user).

Comment: Yeah, the readme file on workspace grid's github page also mentions this but I know how lazy people are (including me) when it comes to reading the manual, so I just left it here :D

Comment: I use a 2x2 grid with the Workspace Grid extension you mention here, then I can change workspaces with **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **Arrow keys**, like in the old Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity desktop.

Comment: For me in Ubuntu 20.04 what worked best was the [Frippery Bottom Panel](https://www.extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/) extension (install, then configure it through GNOME Tweak Tool -> Extensions).

Answer (score 3):

#### Update: Ubuntu 22.04

It seems the old reliable "Workspace Grid" is no longer maintained, and (at this time of typing) not working on 22.04.

There is a fairly nice alternative in [Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) which does this job. One slight drawback is that it doesn't have a workspace indicator for the panel, nor does the [dev have any plans to implement one](https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/issues/106). But there is an "[improved workspace indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3968/improved-workspace-indicator/)" that does this job pretty well.

It's good to be able to have the 2x2 workspace arrangement if that's what one is accustomed to, as I am.

Comment: I was already using the Workspace Matrix under 18.04, but when I upgraded to 20.04, it did not upgrade that extension. I had to do that manually and things went back to normal.