# Something blocks Ctrl+Alt+left/right-arrow keyboard combination

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 18.04 I'm not able to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to anything. To be precise I may bind it to something, but it doesn't work when using the keyboard combination, up/down arrows do however work.

[image: See screenshot here].

The strange thing is that the system detects the keyboard combinations when assigning a key, but not when trying to use them. As a result the keyboard combinations don't work in any other programs either.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47808160/2237467)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> are default shortcuts for "switch to workspace left" and "switch to workspace right" respectively. You can verify that by running

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left
```

(and `right` in place of `left`).

Since by default GNOME shell has single column workspaces these shortcuts show no effects at all (unless you try something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966442/can-i-have-2x2-workspaces-in-ubuntu-17-10)).

To unbind these keyboard combinations, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
```

(similarly for `right`). Then you'll be able to use these combinations for your custom shortcuts.

Comment: Very interesting that it still shows up when i try "get" on these, even though I have removed them from keyboard settings i GUI. However settting doesn't seem to work:
➜  ~ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left []
zsh: no matches found: []
➜  ~ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['']
zsh: no matches found: []

Comment: Worked when using quotes around the brackets, like:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]" `

Comment: @MrMamen Thanks for the info, I edited the answer.

Comment: great! It solves the Fedora30 issue. The Fedora30 setting UI miss this keymap

Comment: thanks, fixed my vscode shortcuts

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that the Ubuntu 18.04 Settings GUI doesn't show all the keyboard shortcuts.

- It doesn't list "Move (Switch) to workspace to the left/right" (even though there is a shortcut assigned).
- It only shows the first keyboard shortcut if there are multiple shortcuts for a command, like for "Move (Switch) to workspace above/below", which actually has a second keybinding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>.

[image]

To see all of the window manager keybindings:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort

org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Super>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']
```

Now, you can see that there are a bunch of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> keybindings that weren't shown in the Settings screen.

To remove the unwanted keybindings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super>Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
```

Now you can use keybindings in other places.

Comment: Another  shortcuts you would remove are, Ctrl+Shift+Alt+ left, move windows to the left workspace, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "[]"`, and similar Ctrl+Shift+Alt+right, move window to the right workspace, <br>`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "[]" `

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the above answers will not help.

For me in Ubuntu 20.04 i have modified `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/group` file (via `sudo`) and commented these lines (marked **bold**):

```
// CTRL-SHIFT toggle section
//
//partial modifier_keys
//xkb_symbols "lctrl_lshift_toggle" {
//    key <LFSH> {
//        type[Group1]="PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
//        symbols[Group1] = [ Shift_L, ISO_Next_Group ]
//    };
//    key <LCTL> { [ Control_L, ISO_Next_Group ] };
//};
//partial modifier_keys
//xkb_symbols "lctrl_lshift_toggle_rev" {
//    key <LFSH> {
//        type[Group1]="PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
//        symbols[Group1] = [ Shift_L, ISO_Prev_Group ]
//    };
//    key <LCTL> { [ Control_L, ISO_Prev_Group ] };
//};
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "rctrl_rshift_toggle" {
    key <RTSH> {
        type[Group1]="PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Shift_R, ISO_Next_Group ]
    };
    key <RCTL> { [ Control_R, ISO_Next_Group ] };
};
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_shift_toggle" {
//    include "group(lctrl_lshift_toggle)"
    include "group(rctrl_rshift_toggle)"
};
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_shift_toggle_bidir" {
//    include "group(lctrl_lshift_toggle_rev)"
    include "group(rctrl_rshift_toggle)"
```

Then logged out and logged in again.
And it helped.