# Can't use CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+RIGHT (LEFT)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.04

Got Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for development needs, but In Jetbrains Rider i am not able to use  `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+[RIGHT|LEFT]` shortcut for code rearranging. Tried to find the shortcut in `settings -> keyboard shorcuts` but failed. Any advice to work it out?

Comment: How many keyboard layouts do you have? How do you switch between them?

Comment: I am using single layout and it's "English(US)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Something blocks Ctrl+Alt+left/right-arrow keyboard combination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041914/something-blocks-ctrlaltleft-right-arrow-keyboard-combination)