# Get old Workspace Switcher back after upgrading to 18.04 Bionic Beaver?

Tags: unity, gnome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I recently upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver and I really miss the old, simpler workspace switcher.  The 4-way quadrant icon in the Task bar was much easier for me to use and think about, better (for me) than the new Activities -> vertical column of workspaces.

Is there a way to get the old Unity workspace switcher back?  I was delighted to find Nemo, which solved my issues with the new Gnome File Manager (versus the old Nautilus in 14.04).  I'm hoping there's a similar solution for the workspace switcher too.

Comment: You can get [2x2 workspace switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966442/can-i-have-2x2-workspaces-in-ubuntu-17-10) with keyboard shortcuts, but I'm not sure about the "4-way quadrant icon". Alternatively you can still install and use Unity on Bionic.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Shell can be customized with extensions, so these may partially meet your wishes.

- You can rearrange workspaces from the vertical layout to the 2x2 layout using the well maintained Gnome Shell extension [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). This extension updates the layout of your workspaces in the Shell overview, and adjusts the <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+arrow</kbd> keys accordingly.
- The 4 quadrant icon in the taskbar is not back, of course, but a click on the "Activities" button will bring you to the overview, and thus also to the workspaces.
- You may complement the experience, if you wish, by adding the extension [Always Zoom Workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/503/always-zoom-workspaces/). This extension ensures that the workspace switcher in the overview is always expanded.

With this setup, the functionality approximates that in the old Unity: workspace arrangement and shortcut keys are similar, and you can change workspaces visually with two clicks.