# How to get 3x3 grid in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I followed the advice from this solution(Note the comment as well) to get the 2x2 grid back:

[Can I have 2x2 workspaces in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966442/can-i-have-2x2-workspaces-in-gnome-3#comment1718266_966444)

When I go into the tweak tool and up the number to 9 workspaces it saves and throws no error. But when I try and use the workspaces I am stuck with a 3x2 grid.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... [cannot reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpx1A.png). Did you also set 3x3 in the extension's preferences?

Comment: That fixed it, I did not see the extension settings button. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pomsky called it -[How to get 3x3 grid in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072444/how-to-get-3x3-grid-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1759705_1072444)

`Did you also set 3x3 in the extension's preferences?`

I totally missed that there was an extension preferences button. Hit that on the chrome extension and update the rows. Simple simple.

Thanks everyone!

[image: Gnome Workspace extension screen preferences]