# Multiple workspaces on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and later with GNOME Shell

Tags: workspaces, gnome-shell

Any idea how to have more than 2 workspaces on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Comment: It's not even obvious how to use a second workspace. Turns out you have to click Activities (if you're using multiple screens then this is usually just on the main one at the top left) and then move your mouse to the right of the main screen and workspaces will pop out. Select the second. Totally unobvious. Note also this doesn't set a second workspace for your second monitor - groan.

Comment: @Snowcrash You can also use your mouse scroll-wheel to switch workspaces while in the Activities overview.

Comment: @pomsky that is seriously useful...!

Answer (score 66):

GNOME shell in Ubuntu 18.04 has a "*dynamic workspaces*" feature by default, which means there is no fixed number of workspaces.

> Workspaces can be created on demand, and are automatically removed when empty.

There will always be an empty workspace below the workspaces you're using. Just open an application window in the second workspace, you should find a third workspace appearing (which is empty) and so on (check the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.en) for more info).

You can disable this feature and switch to fixed number of workspaces. First install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch *Tweaks* and go to the "*Workspaces*" section. Select "Static Workspaces" instead of "*Dynamic Workspaces*" and set the "*Number of Workspaces*" to your preferred one, 4 for example.

[image]

Comment: I'm very pleased to be able to enable the spanning of workspaces across screens. I was finding 'Primary display only' debilitating!

Comment: Also, these new default workspaces cannot be arranged in grid? only vertically?...

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/966442/480481).

Comment: "workspaces" is not visible in gnome tweaks, any help?

Comment: actually i found it, it's in the Settings > Multitasking section

Answer (score 24):

Ubuntu 18.04 comes per default with workspaces.
To use workspaces, click **Activities** on above the vertical bar (dock) (or alternatively press <kbd>Super</kbd>), then move your mouse to the right of your screen to show the **workspaces** in used plus one empty one. Or switch using following [short cuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en).

[image]

### workspaces-to-dock

You can also find a nice gnome-shell extension on following website.

**Extension Homepage:** https://github.com/passingthru67/workspaces-to-dock

To install visit [this page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/) and switch the slide on.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

To add a new workspace, you need to move an app to the new workspace. Use:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+(<kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> arrow).

For moving between workspaces, use:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+(<kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> arrow).

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly Ubuntu 18.04 now uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> (the Windows button) +<kbd>PgDown</kbd> or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.