# minimizing/restoring multiple windows with one action instead of doing that for each window

Tags: 16.04, window

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and have to build/run an Android application on multiple emulator at the same time to compare differences between them. This requires minimizing/restoring windows of multiple emulator for each test which is annoying. I want to know is there a way to do minimizing/restoring those windows with one action instead of doing that for each window? For example is it possible to merge multiple windows into one? Or can I group them?

Note: I do not want to do minimizing/restoring *all* windows, I want to do that for some windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/1159427

Comment: Are the windows you want to minimize overlapping each other? If not, you will see them anyway, if yes, then do not minimize but use Alt+tab or the Windows overview to bring the one you need to the front.