# Workspace switcher icon present in Unity Launcher disappeared from the dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: launcher, gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, workspace-switcher

Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 wiped out the icon "show workspaces" from the desktop launcher. I mean that view below:

[image: show workspaces at old desktop view]

Some posts around are telling to install GNOME extensions and so.
Can't I just get it through some clicks?
Did this config disappear from the standard sys config/settings program?

Note: I DO HAVE workspaces, just NO button to view them all (see bellow):

[image: current desktop view]

Comment: Yeah, IMO it's pretty bad design that the activities tab is on the upper left, but the workspaces show on the right, so you need to move your mouse across the screen to continue the action you wanted to start by clicking the tab in the first place. Killer on the wrist when switching between workspaces a lot.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Use your mouse scroll wheel in the Activities overview to switch workspaces.

Answer (score 5):

You're using GNOME, an environment different from Unity (Ubuntu 18.04 [uses GNOME instead of Unity](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/why-did-ubuntu-drop-unity-mark-shuttleworth-explains) by default), the dock is also different from Unity Launcher. The feature you're looking for is specific to Unity and Launcher.

Ubuntu 18.04 does not have a dedicated workspace switcher icon by default. You can click on the '*Activities*' at the top left corner to see your workspaces at the right side of your screen (along with a spread of the windows on the current desktop). While in the Activities overview, you can switch workspaces using the scroll function of your mouse or touchpad. You can also put a workspace indicator-cum-switcher in the top bar (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163830/480481)).

Alternatively, if you absolutely cannot live without the workspace switcher available in Unity Launcher, you can still install and use Unity on Ubuntu 18.04, refer to this question: [How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481)

Comment: I do not want to create incompatibilities. Wanna stay as close as possible to a standard Ubuntu installation. It is just a simple icon on the launcher. Cant be so difficult, right?

Comment: @user152037 It's kinda difficult, because different environments are like different worlds. You might find this useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966442/can-i-have-2x2-workspaces-in-gnome-3

Comment: you could add a icon to the launcher if using an xserver session to open the overview, basically the same as hitting the super button. It's easy to do, whether worth the effort is debatable. ( create a script running `xdotool key super` , create a .desktop running that script, find an icon, (unity package has the expo icon), add that .desktop to gnome-shell favorites..

Comment: The "Activities" button duplicates the action of the "Show workspaces" icon. Click on "Activities" and you will see your work spaces. Just one click as well, just not on an icon, but on text.

Comment: The "Activities" work differently. I also can only get workspaces view on the right monitor. The left monitor does not show them despite I set "Workspaces span displays" on Tweaks>Workspaces. It was so natural and straightforward on unity, why lose a good idea?