# Ubuntu GNOME: workspace switcher like MATE

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I would like to have on top bar a workspace switcher like Ubuntu MATE has.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by using a [GNOME Shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called "[Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/)". It lets you

> Put an indicator on the panel signaling in which workspace you are, and give you the possibility of switching to another one.

[image]

You can click the indicator and select the destination workspace. You can also scroll up/down to switch to the workspace above/below the current one.