# Make workspaces horizontal?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, just wondering if it's possible to make my workspaces horizontal instead of vertical?
(Preferably without losing my swiping gestures to switch workspaces)?

Comment: did you try workspace grid gnome-shell extension? https://i.stack.imgur.com/INrJR.png

Comment: Related: [Can I have 2x2 workspaces in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/966442/480481)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

workaround

install "Workspace grid" gnome shell extension (https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid)
go to settings and make number of rows and columns as per your wish.

[image]

to make the work spaces static, run the below command
`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false`

example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces
true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
$
```

when dynamic-workspaces true
[image]

when dynamic-workspaces false
[image]

you can use the default keyboard shortcuts or set your preferred ones..

[image]

Comment: Nice. Although, I have a 2-screen setup. It only switches on the screen with the "docker"

Comment: Unfortunately, the GNOME shell extension linked in this answer is no longer being maintained and the code repo mentions "Workspace Matrix" (https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix) as its replacement.