# 21.04 Arrange workspaces horizontally

Tags: gnome, workspaces, wayland, 21.04

In 21.04 workspaces are arranged vertically, so that I have to perform a 4 finger vertical swipe to move between them. I find it unnecessarily inconsistent to have them arranged that way considering that my workspaces in both Windows and macOS are switched with horizontal swipe gestures. It's not something I particularly enjoy to have to stop and think about.

How can I arrange workspaces horizontally, thereby making them consistent with my existing interaction patterns from macOS and Windows?

Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome on Wayland

---

This answer for 18.04 does not solve the problem -- indeed the extension that it suggests I install cannot even be installed (Just says "Error" when flipping the install switch): https://askubuntu.com/a/1115753/428527

Comment: Workspaces on MATE 21.04 are by default horizontal

Comment: @24601 Not sure how I should have phrased the question to make clear that I'm not on MATE. I just took for granted that unless specified otherwise, we're talking about the official flavor. MATEs reliance on unwieldy panels that can't even behave properly on something as simple as a resolution change is misguided at best -- it works on my tiny decade-old 32-bit netbook, but that's about it. It doesn't exactly instil confidence that it now runs Wayland and supports precision multi-touch gestures, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 came out recently with a huge change in its UI, The error you got from the extension is because it is not compatible with Ubuntu 21.04 yet. You can wait for some time so that developers update the extension for Ubuntu 21.04.